# Can't bind to 'filterable' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid-column' in angular 16

Tags: angular, kendo-ui-angular2, angular16

compile error

```
Error: src/app/user-management/user-management.component.html:77:61 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'filterable' since it isn't a known property of 'kendo-grid-column'.
1. If 'kendo-grid-column' is an Angular component and it has 'filterable' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'kendo-grid-column' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

77               <kendo-grid-column title="Edit" [width]="100" [filterable]="false">
                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

i have added below schemas in app.module.ts file

i have imported GridModule in app.module.ts file and kendo-angular dependencies added in package.json file, please find the below code

```
app.module.ts
==========================
import { GridModule, ExcelModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
   imports:[GridModule]
   schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
})

package.json
======================
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^8.0.0", 
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^7.0.1", 
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^7.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^5.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^7.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^9.0.1",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^4.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^4.0.0", 
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^7.0.2", 
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^5.0.0", 
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.6",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3", 
    "@progress/kendo-theme-bootstrap": "^5.4.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^5.4.1", 
}
```